# Calculate X-values at Certain Y-value of High-Degree Polynomial Fit? (Python)

Tags: python, curve-fitting, polynomials

I'm attempting to calculate X-values at a certain Y-value for a very high degree polynomial using Python's numpy function `roots`. I'm using the numpy function `polyfit` to generate the coefficents of my high-degree polynomial. I'm using Python 3.10.

The main issue I'm running into is the fact that the `roots` function doesn't appear to produce correct answers for my X-values at the desired Y-value.

Here's a reproducible example code with some sample data that illustrates the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as poly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    # Declare sample data
    dataX = [0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0]
    dataY = [0.0, -0.008539747658600522, -0.06274870291613317, -0.19444406675443215, -0.36136059621877487, -0.600774409182093, -0.9162127771014803, -1.323039561600279, -1.8023953285501042, -2.3960659331052065, -3.1540213754489517, -4.067701143485799, -5.252273439144881, -6.771579806673188, -8.841718736169389, -11.702002554463427, -10.622244389289413, -7.093229874530799, -4.658886103196484, -2.6582045851707403, -1.046251560907664, 0.26783134185570256, 1.3575816391972544, 2.262728874235532, 2.990654481815292, 3.557426755904812, 3.955698729737411, 4.191874958827449, 4.253204560527751, 4.116558660927984, 3.7485922103648823, 3.1198702528381874]
    polyDegree = 60

    # Perform polynomial fit (ascending coefficent order)
    polyCoeffs = np.flip(np.polyfit(dataX, dataY, polyDegree))

    # Find all X-values at the desired Y-value of polynomial
    y = 0.8
    x = (poly(polyCoeffs) - y).roots().tolist()

    # Filter out all found X-values that are imaginary or beyond desired limits (0, 17)
    i = 0

    while (i < len(x)):
        if (x[i].imag != 0) or (x[i].real < 0) or (x[i].real > 17):
            del x[i]
            i -= 1

        else:
            x[i] = x[i].real

        i += 1

    # Plot data, polynomial and found X-values
    plt.xlim(-1, 18)
    plt.ylim(-20, 20)

    polyDataY = []

    for i in range(len(dataX)):
        value = 0

        for j in range(len(polyCoeffs)):
            value += polyCoeffs[j] * pow(dataX[i], j)

        polyDataY.append(value)

    plt.scatter(dataX, dataY, c = "dodgerblue", label = "Original Data")
    plt.plot(dataX, polyDataY, color = "orange", label = "Polynomial Fit")
    plt.axhline(y, color = "red", label = "Desired Y-value")
    
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.axvline(x[i], color = "forestgreen")

    plt.axvline(99999, color = "forestgreen", label = "Found X-values")

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
    plt.clf()

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

In the example code above, I generate my 60 degree polynomial from some sample data, and store the generated coefficents in the `polyCoeffs` variable. I subsequently try to calculate all X-values at the Y-value of `0.8`, stored in the variables `x` and `y` respectively. I then filter out all imaginary X-value answers, and any answers that are below 0 and above 17. Finally, I plot the original data, fitted polynomial, desired Y-value and all found X-values onto a single plot.

The example code above currently generates the following plot:
[image]

Unfortunately, there appears to be something clearly wrong here.

While one of the found X-values appears to be correctly placed near my desired Y-value, there are a bunch of listed X-values to the right-hand side of the plot:
[image]

I also tried lowering the polynomial degree, as I suspected the `roots` function may simply not be able to calculate all X-values of such a high degree polynomial, but even polynomial of degree 30 appears to give incorrect results for my X-values:
[image]

What is going on here? Why is the `roots` function failing to provide me with the correct X-values for the Y-value of `0.8` here? Is the `roots` function simply not able to calculate X-values of such a high degree polynomial? Is there perhaps a better way of calculating for X for such high-degree polynomials?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: How do you fit a degree-60 polynomial (which has 61 degrees of freedom) to only 35 data points?

Comment: If you plot your "polynomial fit" at a higher density of X values than XData you will see exactly why you get those extra "solutions". High-order polynomials are notoriously "wiggly", and you haven't got enough data points to define a degree-60 polynomial anyway. You might do better with splines.